# Grizzly/Jersey: Request injected into ContainerRequestFilter is null

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, grizzly

I'm trying to implement a `ContainerRequestFilter` that checks some stuff. Ultimately, it shall extract the common name from a SSL client certificate, but I'm not there yet. The filter runs on a Grizzly HTTP Server (Grizzly 2.3.8, no servlet container) and sits in front of a JAX-RS resource (Jersey 2.6).

When I'm trying to inject `org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Request` into the filter, it is null.

```
import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Request;

@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)    // somewhat early
@SkpSecureClient    // name the filter with my own annotation
public class SecureClientFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

  private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

  @Context
  Request request;

  @Override
  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

    if (request == null) {
      log.debug("Unable to inject 'request'");
      // I always end up here
    } else if (request.isSecure()) {
      log.warn("Request is not secure!");
      // do something, e.g. abort request
    } else  {
      log.debug("Request is secure!");
    }
  }
}
```

Injecting the request into a JAX-RS resource, the injection is successful and I can work with it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a bug in Jersey.
Just filed an issue
https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2462

Comment: Thanks. In the ticket you're referring to the related (but fixed) issue https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1960. I can confirm that switching my code to a servlet-container works. I'll wait for the fix and switch back then.